# In the B737, does an IAN NPA require that the G/P is 3° or can the G/P angle vary?

Tags: boeing-737, approach, non-precision-approach

For an IAN Approach to be recognized and work in a Boeing 737, does the Approach G/P need to be exactly 3° or can it vary?

Comment: I assume you meant 3° (the typical G/P angle), not 3%?

Answer (score 1):

**The G/P can deviate from the typical 3 degrees, but not much.**

For any non-precision approach (NPA) flown with VNAV or Integrated Approach Navigation (IAN), the navigation database needs to contain a stored glide path (GP) angle or a suitable waypoint (runway or MAP):

> VNAV should be used only for approaches that have one of the following features:
>
> - a **published GP angle on the LEGS page** for the final approach segment
> - an RWxx waypoint coincident with the approach end of the runway
> - a missed approach waypoint before the approach end of the runway, (e.g.,
>   MXxx).
>
> [...]
>
> The FMC
> obtains the GP angle displayed on the LEGS page from the navigation database. [...] A GP angle
> is coded in the navigation database for nearly all straight-in approach procedures.
>
> [...]
>
> This GP angle is normally defined by the regulatory authority responsible for the
> approach procedure and provides a continuous descent at a constant flight path
> angle for a final approach path that complies with minimum altitudes at
> intermediate step-down fixes. **The typical GP angle is approximately 3.00°, but
> can vary from 2.75° to 3.77°.**

<sup>(Boeing 737 NG FCTM 5.45 - Approach and Missed Approach, emphasis mine)</sup>

As you can see, the GP angle can vary between 2.75 and 3.77 degrees. For IAN, this G/P information is passed on to the AFDS by the FMC. The list of IAN restrictions does not limit the GP angle:

> **IAN Requirements and Restrictions**
>
> - airplanes must be equipped with FMC U10.5 or later and IAN FMA
>   displays
> - dual or single engine approaches are authorized
> - waypoints in the navigation database from the FAF onward may not be
>   modified
> - raw data monitoring is required during localizer based approaches.
>   During FMC based non-ILS approaches, raw data monitoring is
>   recommended when available in accordance with the techniques
>   described in the Non-ILS approach section in this chapter
> - QFE operation is not authorized
> - cold temperature altitude corrections are not permitted
> - RNP appropriate for the approach must be used
> - the autopilot is required until suitable visual reference is established when
>   performing an approach requiring an RNP of 0.15 or lower.

<sup>(Boeing 737 NG FCTM 5.60 - Approach and Missed Approach)</sup>

The FCTM does however says the following about when an approach can be flown with IAN:

> For FMC based approaches, a proper series of legs/waypoints describing the
> approach route including an appropriate vertical path or glide path (GP) angle
> must appear on the LEGS page. A GP angle displayed on the LEGS page means
> the vertical path complies with final approach step-down altitudes (minimum
> altitude constraints). **A glide path angle suitable for an IAN approach is one that
> approximates 3°** and crosses the runway threshold at approximately 50 feet.

<sup>(Boeing 737 NG FCTM 5.61 - Approach and Missed Approach, emphasis mine)</sup>

It does not say if the full range from 2.75 to 3.77 degrees is considered *approximately 3.00°*, but it certainly does not have to be exactly 3.